KTor - how to validate oAuth 2 access tokens for microsoft
I am using KTor framework for OAuth authentication/authorization with microsoft. And it works fine and able to get auth done.

   install(Authentication) {
        oauth("auth-oauth-aad") {
            urlProvider = { Path }
            providerLookup = {
                OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
...
)}}

I use the access token and use decoder to decode the payload. But I am not validating the token itself. My question is, how to validate the access token(singature, validation etc)? Does KTor provide any generic plugin for that? If yes, how to use it?
use decoder for the token. no validation is done yet.

An access token is meant for an API and should be validated only by the API for which it was intended. Ktor doesn't provide a validation functionality for the access tokens.

Okay, after some lookup ended up using com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier library for verification of the token.
Following the snippet if anyone want to use:
rsaPublicKey holds the public key(actually it is X509 certificate)
    val der = Base64.getDecoder().decode(rsaPublicKey.toByteArray())
    val certificateFactory: CertificateFactory  = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
    val certificate: X509Certificate  = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(ByteArrayInputStream(der)) as X509Certificate
    val key: PublicKey = certificate.getPublicKey()
    val algorithm: Algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(key as RSAKey)
    verifier  = JWT.require(algorithm)
        .withIssuer("issuername_as_in_iss")
        .build()

